# Using Angular JS ui-router, is there a way to give routes for a specific set of URL's before the actual route check begins?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**I want to predefine a set of urls and its corresponding redirects in my AngularJS routing file.**

**Please see the routing used in my code.**

```
$stateProvider
  .state('category', {
    url: '/cat' + '/:catId',
    views: {
      main: {
        templateUrl: categoryUrl,
        controller: categoryContorller
      }
    }
  })
  .state('departments', {
    url: '/departments' + '/:deptId',
    views: {
      main: {
        templateUrl: departmentsTemplate,
        controller: departmentsController
      }
    }
  })
```

What I need here is, when some particular category name comes i have to redirect it to another url.
ie,

```
 For the following urls,
 http://localhost:3000/cat/cat1 redirect to 
 http://localhost:3000/cat/cat4 

 http://localhost:3000/cat/cat2 redirect to 
 http://localhost:3000/cat/cat5 

 http://localhost:3000/cat/cat3 redirect to 
 http://localhost:3000/cat/cat6
```

When the url  http://localhost:3000/cat/cat1 is hit the site should redirect to http://localhost:3000/cat/cat4, and the same rule for cat2 and cat3 as well.

How can i handle this with AngularJS ui-router? Please share your valuable ideas.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: maybe with `$urlRouterProvider.when('/cat/cat1', '/cat/cat4');`

Comment: For UI-Router 0.x use `$stateChangeStart` events; for 1.x, use transitions.

Comment: @georgeawg If we use $StateChangeStart event, the site first tries to load the old url and then the old page will start loading and then the page is redirected to new url right? ie. There is a slight delay in redirection.

Comment: With `$stateChangeStart` one aborts the undesired state change, then initiates the desired state change. The route change (and the $location change that triggered it) can be prevented by calling `preventDefault` method of the event.